# Pick off JSON result

Tags: javascript, json

I am using WifiWizard to get a scan of the current network. To do this I am using the following

```
    WifiWizard.startScan(success, fail);

    function success()
    {
    WifiWizard.getScanResults(networks,fail);   
    }

    function fail()
    {
    alert('not found');
    }    

    function networks(networkResult)
    {
    result =(JSON.stringify(networkResult));
    alert(JSON.stringify(networkResult));
    }
```

Which indeed supplies me the results of the network like such

```
networks = [
{   "level": signal_level, // raw RSSI value
    "SSID": ssid, // SSID as string, with escaped double quotes: "\"ssid name\""
    "BSSID": bssid // MAC address of WiFi router as string
    "frequency": frequency of the access point channel in MHz
    "capabilities": capabilities // Describes the authentication, key management, and encryption schemes supported by the access point.
    "timestamp": timestamp in microseconds (since boot) when this result was last seen.
}
]
```

But I only want the BSSID I thought this would be `networkResult.BSSID` but this is undefined. How do I get just the BSSID>

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` to get JSON object. `var result = JSON.parse(response); var bssId = result[0].BSSID;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The networkResult variable is an array, so you need the first element of it:

```
networkResult[0]['BSSID']
```

or

```
networkResult[0].BSSID
```